# No horizontal word stretching

Tags: formatting

The following is probably a very easy-to-answer question with loads of answers on this page but I can't find any useful answers ... probably because I don't know exactly what to search  for.

**Question**

How do I stop any word stretching on a line in order to get a uniform white space between words on evert line?

I have a document with rather narrow columns and it looks horrible with word stretching so what I what is the same as at the bottom of the second coulmn on page 2 of the article at http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb39-2/tb122complete.pdf (the copyright bit).

P.S. I would like this both in a document that I compile using `pdflatex` and in another document that I compile using `latex` --> `dvips` --> `ps2pdf`, in case it makes any difference.

Comment: Maybe using `\RaggedRight`(`ragged2e` package)?

Comment: @Bernard Wauw! That was embarrassingly simple. `:-)` How do I suppress all the `underfull \hbox` warnings that follow from this?

Comment: I got it myself: `\global\hbadness=10000` in the preamble.

Comment: Fine! This being said, you may as usual indicate by hand some hyphenation points to help the compiler hyphenate some words if iy's not too long.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: note settimg hbadness doesn't stop the lines being underfull it just stops tex warning you about them, perhaps that's Ok but setting hbadness=10000 means you don't want to be told about even the most horrible typesetting that tex can make according to its own measure of how bad the output is.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for that. I have checked the documents after I typeset them and they look okay. Also, this is actually the very first document where I've used `\global\hbadness=10000` -- normally, I would never do this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.